# How to check in GAP whether two nilpotent Lie algebras are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, gap

Let `L1` and `L2` be two nilpotent Lie algebras. How can I check that two nilpotent Lie algebras are isomorphic in GAP? For example, GAP has `IsNilpotentLieAlgebra` to check whether a Lie algebra is nilpotent. Is there a similar function named like `AreIsomorphicLieAlgebras` to check whether `L1` and `L2` are isomorphic or not?

First I present two nilpotent Lie algebras as follows:

```
SCTL:=EmptySCTable(6,0,"antisymmetric");;
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,2,[1,3]);
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,3,[1,4]);
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,4,[1,5]);;
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,2,3,[1,5]);;
H:=LieAlgebraByStructureConstants(Rationals,SCTL);
```

and

```
SCTL:=EmptySCTable(6,0,"antisymmetric");;
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,2,[1,3]);
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,3,[1,4]);
SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,4,[1,5]);;
S:=LieAlgebraByStructureConstants(Rationals,SCTL);
```

but trying to call `IsomorphismLieAlgebras(H, S);` I get an following error

```
Error, Variable: 'IsomorphismLieAlgebras' must have a value
```

Now I know answer of  this question for nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension at most 6 by using LieAlgDB package.

I don't know about nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension 7 or 8.

I have two Lie algebras of domension 8. See  L : [x1, x2] = [x3, x4] = x6, [x1, x5] = [x2, x3] = x7, [x1, x7] = [x2, x4] = [x4, x5] = [x6, x3] = x8, and K : [x1, x2] = [x3, x4] = x6, [x1, x5] = [x2, x3] = x7, [x1, x7] = [x6, x3] = [x2, x4] = x8.
Are L and L1 isomporphic?

Comment: You can do this without GAP in many cases by comparing easy invariants like dimension, nilpotency class, commutator dimension, dimension of its center, maximal dimension of an abelian ideal etc., or just solving the equations assuming an isomorphism. What example do you have?

Comment: $T_2$ has a $5$-dimensional abelian ideal, namely $\langle x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8\rangle$, but $T_1$ has not. So they are not isomorphic.

Comment: You can write a program yourself. I have done this and it works. Then you also see how it depends on the field, from the polynomial equations. With GAP you could also do this, if it is not yet included.

Comment: @Afsaneh the Sophus package has a function `AreIsomorphicNilpotentLieAlgebras` - see [here](https://gap-packages.github.io/sophus/doc/chap3.html#X87B4D4C384E9B3DF). I also agree with the closure. The answer may depend on your setup - how do you create these Lie algebras in GAP, so it would be helpful if you add those details.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and place a properly formatted code there, instead of hiding it in a comment. If the question will then be reopened, it will be possible to post an answer. One can't post an answer on closed questions. Also, have you tried the Sophus package for these Lie algebras? What happened?

Comment: In this pacakge don't define a Lie algebra similar to my way.

Comment: You state that GAP has `IsNilpotentLieAlgebra` - where is it, I can find it in GAP or any packages.

Comment: Indeed, Sophus has "AreIsomorphicNilpotentLieAlgebras: for nilpotent Lie algebras with nilpotent presentation", and the package says that it works with Lie algebras over finite fields, so it will not help here.

Answer (score 1):

The two Lie algebras in question are not isomorphic. This can be verified using `LieAlgebraIdentification` from the [LieAlgDB package](https://gap-packages.github.io/liealgdb/). This function works for solvable Lie algebras of dimension 2,3, or 4, and for nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension 5 or 6 ([see its documentation here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/liealgdb-2.2/doc/chap2.html#X8068FF417F93FCD2)).

```
gap> SCTL:=EmptySCTable(6,0,"antisymmetric");;
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,2,[1,3]);
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,3,[1,4]);
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,4,[1,5]);;
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,2,3,[1,5]);;
gap> H:=LieAlgebraByStructureConstants(Rationals,SCTL);
<Lie algebra of dimension 6 over Rationals>
gap> SCTL:=EmptySCTable(6,0,"antisymmetric");;
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,2,[1,3]);
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,3,[1,4]);
gap> SetEntrySCTable( SCTL,1,4,[1,5]);;
gap> S:=LieAlgebraByStructureConstants(Rationals,SCTL);
<Lie algebra of dimension 6 over Rationals>
gap> LoadPackage("LieAlgDB");
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Loading  LieAlgDB 2.2 (A library of Lie algebras)
by Serena Cicalò (cicalo@science.unitn.it),
   Willem de Graaf (http://www.science.unitn.it/~degraaf), and
   Csaba Schneider (http://www.mat.ufmg.br/~csaba/).
Homepage: https://gap-packages.github.io/liealgdb/
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
true
gap> LieAlgebraIdentification(H);
rec( isomorphism := CanonicalBasis( <Lie algebra of dimension 
    6 over Rationals> ) -> [ v.1, v.2, v.3, v.4, v.5, v.6 ], 
  name := "N6_6( Rationals )", parameters := [  ] )
gap> LieAlgebraIdentification(S);
rec( isomorphism := CanonicalBasis( <Lie algebra of dimension 
    6 over Rationals> ) -> [ v.1, v.2, v.3, v.4, v.5, v.6 ], 
  name := "N6_7( Rationals )", parameters := [  ] )
```

The `name` component in the output is different for `H` and `S`.

Comment: Also I have many Lie algebras of domension 8. For example  
L : [x1, x2] = [x3, x4] = x6, [x1, x5] = [x2, x3] = x7,
[x1, x7] = [x2, x4] = [x4, x5] = [x6, x3] = x8,  and
K : [x1, x2] = [x3, x4] = x6, [x1, x5] = [x2, x3] = x7,
[x1, x7] = [x6, x3] = [x2, x4] = x8

Comment: I don't know about  nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension at least 8.

Comment: In this case I'm afraid following Dietrich Burde's suggestion is the only way to go. You may wish to edit your question and add GAP input to construct two algebras of dimension 8 _there_, for the ease of someone interested in helping with an answeer.